# Will part of my index be used if i have an index on A,B,C,D but my query selects A,B,D

Tags: mysql, indexing

If I have an index of A,B,C i know that i get benefits of the index when selecting with A, A,B or A,B,C but not A,C

However i'm wondering now if I have an index of A,B,C,D but do a select of A,B,D do i still get the benefits of the index from A,B?

Comment: By `selects A,B,D` you mean `where A = AND B= AND D = `, yes your index will be used, it isn't optimal

Comment: correct, `A,B,D` means where `A = ? AND B = ? and D = ?` i know for `A,B,C` any left combination will utilize the index, but wasn't sure if the index got dropped if i introduced D. I tried to do an explain but since my mock data wasn't large the index didn't really seem consistent

Answer (score 0):

> However I'm wondering now if I have an index of A,B,C,D but do a
> select of A,B,D do I still get the benefits of the index from A,B?

From the comment section

> A,B,D means where A = ? AND B = ? and D = ?

The index will be used for `A =` and `B =` clause, still it isn't the optimal one.

**Testing**

Consider the following data which can be found on [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xl7i-B04) as well

```
create table test_tbl (
  A varchar(25),
  B varchar(25),
  C varchar(25),
  D varchar(25),
  key a_b_c_d(A,B,C,D)
) ;


insert into test_tbl values ('AA','BB','CC','DD');


set @@cte_max_recursion_depth = 1000000;
  
INSERT INTO test_tbl (A,B,C,D)
WITH RECURSIVE cte (n) AS (
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM cte WHERE n < 100000
)
SELECT IF (RAND() < 0.2, concat(n,'AA'), 'AA'),'BB1','CC1','DD1'
FROM cte;
```

**Query I**

```
explain select t.* 
from test_tbl t  
where A='AA' and B='BB' and D='DD' ;
```

Result

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  t   null    ref a_b_c_d a_b_c_d 206 const,const 1   10.00   Using where; Using index
```

We can see that the index is being used.

The optimal query for the given index would be

```
explain select t.* 
from test_tbl t  
where A='AA' and B='BB' and C='CC' and D='DD' ;
```

Result,

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  t   null    ref a_b_c_d a_b_c_d 412 const,const,const,const 1   100.00  Using index
```